# Regular expression to get the value from []

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have a string as under

> "=[Book1]Sheet1!$F$13"

The needed output being Book1

Is there any regular expression to do this?

Presently I am using string splitting to get the work done.

```
string input = "=[Book1]Sheet1!$F$13";
var res = input.Split('[')[1].Split(']')[0];
```

Thanks

Comment: looks like the string splitting is working pretty well - I'd be interested to know what the performance change is if you implement a regex instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you need is the Excel workbook's name, this will do:

```
string res = null;
Match m = Regex.Match(input, @"^=\[(.+)\].+$");

if (m.Success)
{
    res = m.Groups[1].Value;
}
```

Comment: `string res = null` would be correct, implicit typing will fail when assigning to null. Also, double escaping is not correct in verbatim string.

Comment: `\[(.+)\]` matches anything between the `[]`.

Answer (score 0):

try:

string regex = "[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,}";

If you search for the 1st match with this pattern, you will always get what is inside the []